# BigInteger equivalent in Swift?

Tags: swift, integer, biginteger, largenumber

Is there an equivalent to Java's `BigInteger` class in Swift? I am tying to do large calculations in Swift with positive integers larger than `UInt64` maximum valye.

What is the best way to handle these numbers in Swift?

Comment: Decimal types are generally for financial calculation, not just arbitrary precision. In Java you want BigInteger, as your title indicates, not BigDecimal as your question body indicates. Cocoa does not include any BigInteger type.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `NSDecimalNumber` class from Cocoa. It is not infinite precision, but it can represent 38 decimal digits of precision, which may be enough for what you need.

Comment: Is this a different precision to `Double`?

Comment: float32 has about sd 7, float 64 sd 16, float80 sd34

Comment: Now it is [Decimal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/decimal) struct :)

Comment: Decimal doesn't work correctly, for example, the factorial of 45 is `119622220865480194561963161495657715064383733760000000000`  but code with Decimal produces `119622220865480194561963161495657715064000000000000000000`

Comment: @BohdanSavych: I did say it's not infinite precision

Comment: @BohdanSavych What about more than 45 digit?

Answer (score 11):

I found a prototype of BigInt in the official Swift repository: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/Prototypes/BigInt.swift

You can probably just copy it into your project and use it. Maybe some day it will be added to the standard library.

Comment: Swift 5.8 is introducing `StaticBigInt` [SE-0368](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0368-staticbigint.md). I don't pretend to fully understand it, but the Hacking With Swift writeup suggests this will make it ["easier to add new, larger integer types in the future"](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/256/whats-new-in-swift-5-8).

Answer (score 9):

I'm also working on a BigNumber library with which you can do some big number calculations. Actually the library is based on the GNU Multiple Precision (GMP) library and I wrote an Objective-C / Swift wrapper.
Currently big integer mathematics, including a lot of operator overloading, is possible.
A code example goes like:

```
var err : NSError?
var bi1 = BigInt(nr: 12468642135797531)
var bi2 = BigInt(nr: "12345678901011121314151617181920", error: &err)
var res = bi1 * bi2
println("Multiply 2 BigInts: bi1 * bi2 = \(res.toString())")
```

which results in:

```
Multiply 2 BigInts: bi1 * bi2 = 153933852140173822960829726365674325601913839520
```

You can find the library at: https://github.com/githotto/osxgmp

Comment: Can it be used in app submitted to Appstore? I guess it be cannot due to license restrictions.

Comment: I'm not an expert in GNU- and AppStore-licence/restrictions, but IMHO as long as you keep the included references intact, such that the original authors can be identified, it should be no problem. By the way I'm happy to hear that the library is of use to you! Maybe you can share with us for what purposes it is used?!

Comment: Usually the GPLs are interpreted in a way, that any software including it (compiled or linked) need to be GPL'd too. For my company this is a no-go for using any GPL'd code. This is also the opinion of our lawyers.

Comment: can it convert Data(NSData) to BigInt ?

Comment: No it can not directly convert Date(NSDate) to BigInt, but if you try something like:
        var date: NSDate()
        let dateAsInt = Int32(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
        var dateAsBigInt = BitInt(nr: dateAsInt)
you should probably get wat you want. I have tried this on my computer yet, but this is probably the way I would do it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

I have written a big integer and big double implementation for swift, that doesn't require any additional library. Just copy it into your project. It supports whole Numbers (BInt) and Fractions (BDouble) with most of the common math operators like addition, subtraction, multiplication, exponentiation, modulus and division. Some optimized math functions like factorial or gcd are also implemented.

Here are some code examples:

```
// Create a new number:
let num = BInt(232)
print(num) // prints "232"

// You can also use Strings to create a number:
let veryBig = BInt("-827846184963421874362418746238453267452971345218746328715380000000000")

// Every standard math operator works well, even with normal Integers
// Visit the github page for more informations
let v0 = (BInt(5) + BInt(4)) - BInt(3)
let v1 = veryBig * 1000
let v2 = vergBig ^ num
let v3 = (veryBig ^ 50000) / (BInt(2) ^ 900) + 1
let v4 = gcd(abs(veryBig), num)

// BDouble is very similar, you can find a detailed description on Github
let fraction = BDouble("27", over: "31")
print(fraction) // prints "27/31"
```

You can use it freely without giving me credit, and please contribute if you want.

You can find it here: https://github.com/mkrd/Swift-Big-Integer

Comment: can it convert Data(NSData) to BigInt ?

Comment: Great lib... simple drag n drop... works for double as well.

Answer (score 7):

Here it is.

https://github.com/dankogai/swift-pons

Actually BigInt is just a part of it.  In addition to BigInt you get:

- generic Rational that takes form Int8 to BigInt as numerator and denominator
- generic Complex that takes either integers (gaussian integers) or real number types not only Double and Float but also Rational.
- Purely swift.  Runs not only on OS X, iOS and tvOS but also Linux.  Works happily in Playground.

But the best of all, it is protocol-oriented so you can extend whole integer like:

```
import PONS

func fib<T:POInteger>(n:T)->T { // with a little better algorithm
    if n < T(2) { return n }
    var (a, b) = (T(0), T(1))
    for _ in 2...n {
        (a, b) = (b, a+b)
    }
    return b
}

let F11 = fib(11 as Int8)
let F13 = fib(13 as UInt8)
let F23 = fib(23 as Int16)
let F24 = fib(24 as UInt16)
let F46 = fib(46 as Int32)
let F47 = fib(47 as UInt32)
let F92 = fib(92 as Int64)
let F93 = fib(93 as UInt64)
let F666 = fib(666 as BigInt)
```

Dan the Number Generator

Comment: can it convert Data(NSData) to BigInt ?

Comment: Nice example, but very inefficient for huge fibs, e.g. F666. For that you should use a Matrix

Answer (score 5):

I wrote library that allows you to work with big integers in Swift. In similar manner like Java's BigInteger. There are also operator overloads to make work more convenient.
Example:

```
let a = BigInteger("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000001")!
let b = 999_999_999
let c = a + b // 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000
```

https://github.com/kirsteins/BigInteger

Comment: Does this also work on iOS for arm64? Also are there any steps on how to include this in the iOS project listed somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it works on arm64. Here is a good guide on how to add the framework dependency https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift#installation. You can use this guide with BigInteger.

Comment: Thanks, I trying following the steps you suggested , but I am unable to import it in my code after adding it. Could you record a video or list the steps with screenshots?

Comment: Take a not that you have to build the framework either separately or by by building the app in order for syntax highlighting to work. Will try to record a video when I have some time.

Comment: @Kirsteins How to covert Data into BigInteger using your library ?