# Simple Swift Fibonacci program crashing (Project Euler 2)

Tags: swift, exc-bad-instruction

I am trying to solve the second problem on Project Euler. The problem is as follows:

---

*Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.*

---

I think I've written a solution, but when I try to run my code it crashes my Swift playground and gives me this error message:

> Playground execution aborted: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

---

```
var prev = 0
var next = 1
var num = 0
var sum = 0

for var i = 1; i < 400; i++ {
    num = prev + next
    if next % 2 == 0 {
        sum += next
    }
    prev = next
    next = num
}
print(sum)
```

---

The weird thing is, if I set the counter on my loop to less than 93, it works fine. Explicitly setting the variable names to Double does not help. Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: This might interest you: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60875/project-euler-2-even-fibonacci-numbers-in-swift.

Comment: Same problem (on a 32-bit platform) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317369/using-for-loop-for-fibonacci-series-to-print-values-it-will-print-up-to-47-value.

Comment: @MartinR Codereview is the place to go when you want to improve _working_ code.Code that crashes is off-topic for codereview.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger: I know. My intention was not to suggest that OP posts his problem at CR. It was just meant as *"Have a look at this code (which is about the same PE problem)  and the reviews, it might interest you."*

Comment: @MartinR Oh, sorry for that. I read it a bit fast and didn't notice it was a link to an actual question instead of the home page of the site.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing *weird* about this at all. Do you know how large the 400 fibonacci number is?

```
176023680645013966468226945392411250770384383304492191886725992896575345044216019675
```

Swift `Int64` or `UInt64` simply cannot handle that large of a number. The later can go up to `18446744073709551615` at max - not even close.

If you change your variables to be doubles it works but will be inaccurate:

```
var prev : Double = 0
var next : Double = 1
var num : Double = 0
var sum : Double = 0
```

will yield

> 2.84812298108489e+83

which is kind of close to the actual value of

> 1.76e+83

Luckily you do not need to get values that big. I would recommend not writing a for loop but a while loop that calculates the next fibonacci number until the break condition is met *whose values do not exceed four million*.

Comment: Yes, it's a huge number, but I thought computers were good at working with huge numbers. If I'm understanding you correctly, the problem is not my code but the fact that Swift cannot handle such a large number? The problems on Project Euler are meant to be solved by using a computer program so how can I use Swift to solve it?

Comment: @makenaw firstly: because that number simply exceeds what a builtin integer can hold. *Period*. Secondly: you can easily calculate the answer to that question in swift if you take a look at my last paragraph. Your code is generally fine, yes. The only problem is the for-loop.

Comment: @makenaw: I have done some PE problems, and almost all of them have a solution that fits into a 64-bit integer.

Comment: You could also implement your own arbitrary-precision class (in this case you only need to implement addition). Represent integers as a mutable array of digits. Of course, you are still limited, but not by the size of Uint. You are limited by the amount of memory available on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

The Fibonacci numbers become very large quickly.  To compute large Fibonacci numbers, you need to implement some kind of `BigNum`.  Here is a version the makes a `BigNum` that is implemented internally as an array of digits.  For example, `12345` is implemented internally as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.  This makes it easy to represent arbitrarily large numbers.

Addition is implemented by making the two arrays the same size, then `map` is used to add the elements, finally the `carryAll` function restores the array to single digits.

For example `12345 + 67`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] + [6, 7]            // numbers represented as arrays
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] + [0, 0, 0, 6, 7]   // pad the shorter array with 0's
[1, 2, 3, 10, 12]                   // add the arrays element-wise
[1, 2, 4, 1, 2]                     // perform carry operation
```

Here is the implementation of `BigNum`.  It is also `CustomStringConvertible` which makes it possible to print the result as a `String`.

```
struct BigNum: CustomStringConvertible {
    var arr = [Int]()

    // Return BigNum value as a String so it can be printed
    var description: String { return arr.map(String.init).joined() }

    init(_ arr: [Int]) {
        self.arr = carryAll(arr)
    }

    // Allow BigNum to be initialized with an `Int`
    init(_ i: Int = 0) {
        self.init([i])
    }

    // Perform the carry operation to restore the array to single
    // digits
    func carryAll(_ arr: [Int]) -> [Int] {
        var result = [Int]()

        var carry = 0
        for val in arr.reversed() {
            let total = val + carry
            let digit = total % 10
            carry = total / 10
            result.append(digit)
        }

        while carry > 0 {
            let digit = carry % 10
            carry = carry / 10
            result.append(digit)
        }

        return result.reversed()
    }

    // Enable two BigNums to be added with +
    static func +(_ lhs: BigNum, _ rhs: BigNum) -> BigNum {
        var arr1 = lhs.arr
        var arr2 = rhs.arr

        let diff = arr1.count - arr2.count

        // Pad the arrays to the same length
        if diff < 0 {
            arr1 = Array(repeating: 0, count: -diff) + arr1
        } else if diff > 0 {
            arr2 = Array(repeating: 0, count: diff) + arr2
        }

        return BigNum(zip(arr1, arr2).map { $0 + $1 })
    }
}

// This function is based upon this question:
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/52975875/1630618

func fibonacci(to n: Int) {
    guard n >= 2 else { return }
    var array = [BigNum(0), BigNum(1)]
    for i in 2...n {
        array.append(BigNum())
        array[i] = array[i - 1] + array[i - 2]
        print(array[i])
    }
}

fibonacci(to: 400)
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 8
> ...
> 67235063181538321178464953103361505925388677826679492786974790147181418684399715449
> 108788617463475645289761992289049744844995705477812699099751202749393926359816304226
> 176023680645013966468226945392411250770384383304492191886725992896575345044216019675
> ```