# Fibonacci in swift playground

Tags: swift

can someone please guide me why this code that i wrote only works until `userInput` is less than 94 ?

```
   func calculateFibonacciFucntionUntil(userInput: Int) {
    var array = [0 ,1]
    for i in 2...userInput {
      array.append(i)
      array[i] = array[i - 1] + array[i - 2]
        print(array[i])
    }
}

calculateFibonacciFucntionUntil(userInput: 10)
```

Comment: Check out this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52980180/1630618

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `Int` can only store 64bit numbers (on 64bit platforms) and Fibonacci 95 is bigger than the maximum number that can be stored on 64bits.

Fibonacci 95 is `31 940 434 634 990 099 905`, while the biggest number `Int64` can hold is `2^63-1 = 9 223 372 036 854 775 807`.

You can use `Decimal` for storing larger numbers than what `Int` can hold `Decimal.greatestFiniteMagnitude` is `3.4028236692093865e+165`.

However, Swift doesn't have a built-in type for storing arbitrarily large numbers, so if you want to do that you'll either need to use a 3rd party library or implement an appropriate data type yourself.

Comment: The largest value the (signed) Int64 can hold is 2^63-1.