# How to calculate the 21! (21 factorial) in Swift?

Tags: swift, math

I am making fuction that calculates factorial in Swift. Like this:

```
func factorial(factorialNumber: UInt64) -> UInt64 {
    if factorialNumber == 0 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return factorialNumber * factorial(factorialNumber - 1)
    }
}

let x = factorial(20)
```

This fuction can calculate until 20!.

I think factorial(21) is bigger than UINT64_MAX.

How to accurately calculate 21! (21 factorial) in Swift?

Comment: I think this isn't possible in pure Swift. At least not trivial. I don't know any language that can calculate such numbers out of the box.

Comment: I haven't used it personally, but you can try a library like such as https://github.com/kirsteins/BigInteger

Comment: It might be ugly, but if you store the result of each iteration in a string instead of a UIint, you can multiple it like it was in paper. Not efficient, the BigInteger library looks more useful, but this is an option too.

Comment: what for do you need the factorial ? if it is a part of equation (like in some division) then you can compute the equation in iterative steps  keeping the subresults small enough to fit into variable. Another way is use `H,L` style variables (2 variables per single number)  or use bigint lib of some kind. If you go for bigints then may be this [Fast exact bigint factorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333853/2521214) could help a bit

Comment: @dasdom allmost any dialect of Smalltalk would compute 21! out of the box

Comment: @dasdom: Python, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unsigned 64 bit integer has a maximum value of 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. While 21! = 51,090,942,171,709,440,000. For this kind of case, you need a Big Integer type. I found a question about Big Integer in Swift. There's a library for Big Integer in that link.

[BigInteger equivalent in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531914/biginteger-equivalent-in-swift)

Answer (score 12):

```
func factorial(_ n: Int) -> Double {
  return (1...n).map(Double.init).reduce(1.0, *)
}
```

1. `(1...n)`: We create an array of all the numbers that are involved in the operation (i.e: `[1, 2, 3, ...]`).
2. `map(Double.init)`: We change from `Int` to `Double` because we can represent bigger numbers with Doubles than with Ints (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). So, we now have the array of all the numbers that are involved in the operation as `Doubles` (i.e: `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ...]`).
3. `reduce(1.0, *)`: We start multiplying `1.0` with the first element in the array (`1.0*1.0 = 1.0`), then the result of that with the next one (`1.0*2.0 = 2.0`), then the result of that with the next one (`2.0*3.0 = 6.0`), and so on.

Step 2 is to avoid the overflow issue.

Step 3 is to save us from explicitly defining a variable for keeping track of the partial results.

Comment: It would be nice if you could append your answer with a comentary of the logic behind your answer

Comment: Can u provide some explanation behind this ?

Comment: I added some explanation.

Comment: This will crash if you pass 0 or a negative number to the function.

Comment: This isn't a useful solution since a Double only supports about 17 digits of precision.

Answer (score 3):

Did you think about using a double perhaps? Or NSDecimalNumber?

Also calling the same function recursively is really bad performance wise.

How about using a loop:

```
let value = number.intValue - 1

var product = NSDecimalNumber(value: number.intValue)

for i in (1...value).reversed() {
    product = product.multiplying(by: NSDecimalNumber(value: i))
}
```

Comment: Minor nit: The result of a multiplicative equation is its "product", not "sum."

Comment: Please note that even with `NSDecimalNumber`, the result is only accurate up to 38!. After that, precision is lost and the result is no longer accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to give up precision you can use a Double to roughly calculate factorials up to 170:

```swift
func factorial(_ n: Int) -> Double {
    if n == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    var a: Double = 1
    for i in 1...n {
        a *= Double(i)
    }
    return a
}
```

If not, use a big integer library.

Comment: This isn't a useful solution since a Double only supports about 17 digits of precision.