# How to parse Int with a value more than 2147483647 from JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have some JSON Dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
biography = "";
externalUrl = "";
followersCount = 467;
followingsCount = 428;
fullName = dima;
hasAnonymousProfilePicture = 1;
id = 2673580202;
isBusiness = 0;
isPrivate = 0;
mediaCount = 0;
picture = "http://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/11906329_960233084022564_1448528159_a.jpg";
username = "kmr.dma";
}
```

So I'm parsing 'id' parameter like this:

```
guard let userID = array["id"] as? Int else {
   return
}
```

And I'm getting the value like : `-1621387094`
Thats because Int.max() is `2147483647` and my id is `2673580202`

So the problem is clear but how to get over it ?

Comment: Try to parse it as `Double`.

Comment: The usual answer is to always treat ids as strings, because it's very unlikely that you're doing arithmetics with them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25531914/3141234

Comment: @MaxPevsner it worked) post your answer below

Comment: You need another type - Int64 or Double

Comment: Int64 is your friend. UInt64 if there are no negative values.

Comment: Something like `guard let userId = (dict["id"] as? NSNumber)?.longLongValue` should work.

Comment: @MartinR post your answer I'll approve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Int` can be a 32-bit or 64-bit integer, depending on the platform.
As already said in the comments, you need `Int64` or `UInt64` to store
a value > 2147483647 on all platforms.

You cannot cast from `AnyObject` to `Int64` directly, therefore 
the conversion is via `NSNumber`:

```
guard let userId = (dict["id"] as? NSNumber)?.longLongValue  else { return }
```

For Swift 3, replace `longLongValue` by `int64Value`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to parse it as `Double`. `Double` is much bigger than `Int`.

Example:

```
guard let userID = array["id"] as? Double else {
    return
}
```

Comment: Parsing an id as a `Double` is a terrible idea. Rounding could make two different ids equal... It should be parsed as a `String` if `Int64` is not enough.

Comment: `Double` isn't "much bigger" than `Int`. They're both `8` bytes. `Double`'s range is much bigger, but that's because it trades precision for range.

Comment: @deadbeef, if you pay attention to the JSON, you will notice that id is not defined as `String`. I assumed, OP cant change the JSON format.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: `Int` can be 32-bit or 64-bit, depending on the platform. In this case it is apparently 32-bit. `Double` has a 54(?) bit mantissa, so it is exact up to 2^54. That is better than a 32-bit Int, but worse than a 64-bit Int.

Comment: @MartinR I know, but I'm not sure where you're going with that

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: It was just a response to your claim that Int is 8 bytes, which is not true in general.

Comment: Ah yes, I misspoke. I only develop for 64 bit macs. I meant `Int64`