# A number bigger than 9223372036854775807

Tags: swift, int

In a program that I am making, I require rather large numbers, for instance `1000000000000000000` also known as a quintillion. This number is just within the regions of the largest possible `Int()` in swift. Lets say I wanted to store 10 quintillion (10 x 10^19) into a variable. What would be the best way to approach this problem, if there is a solution at all...

In addition to this I would need to find a way to store this in UserDefaults.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BigInteger equivalent in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531914/biginteger-equivalent-in-swift).

Comment: @MartinR I edited it to say why it is different

Comment: Look into `Decimal`/`NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: Using NSDecimalNumber is one of the answers given in the linked-to Q&A

Comment: @MartinR But that doesn't make it a duplicate question. This question has nothing to do with Java's `BigInteger`.

Comment: I would consider is a duplicate of *"I am tying to do large calculations in Swift with positive integers larger than UInt64's maximum number. What is the best way to handle these numbers?"*

Comment: @MartinR but my question requires it to be functional with NSUserDefaults, which that question doesn't help at all with.