# How to print all the digits in a large number of 10 power 25 in swift?

Tags: swift, algorithm, double, factorial, largenumber

I have been working on a hacker rank problem where I have to print a number which is a factorial of 25. Here is the code I used.

```
func extraLongFactorials(n: Int) -> Void {
    let factorialNumber = factorial(number: n)

    var arrayForStorage: [Int] = []

    var loop = factorialNumber
    while (loop > 0) {
       let digit = loop.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 10)

       arrayForStorage.append(Int(digit))

       loop /= 10
    }

    arrayForStorage = arrayForStorage.reversed()
    var returnString = ""
    for element in arrayForStorage {
       returnString = "\(returnString)\(element)"
    }

    print(returnString)
}

func factorial(number: Int) -> Double {
    if number == 0 || number == 1 {
       return 1
    } else if number == 2 {
       return 2
    } else {
       return Double(number) * factorial(number: number - 1)
    }
}
```

But when I try to print the factorial number it just prints `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015511210043330982408266888` when it should print
`15511210043330985984000000`.

I think for a Double number `truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 10)` method is not giving me the exact number of the remainder. Because when I tried to print the truncatingRemainder of 15511210043330985984000000 it is giving me as `8`. Here is the code.

```
let number: Double = 15511210043330985984000000
print(number.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 10))
```

So finally I didn't find any solution for the problem of how to split the large number and add it into an array. Looking forward for the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830823/1630618

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @vacawama

Comment: Can I make your question a duplicate of that one, or do you still want more information on why your approach wasn't working?

Comment: I want to know why truncatingRemainder is not working properly for large number.

Answer (score 1):

Type `Double` stores a number as a `mantissa` and an `exponent`.  The `mantissa` represents the significant figures of the number, and the `exponent` represents the magnitude of the number.  A `Double` can only represent about `16` significant figures, and your number has `26` digits, so you can't accurately store `15511210043330985984000000` in a `Double`.

```
let number1: Double = 15511210043330985984000000
let number2: Double = 15511210043330985984012345

if number1 == number2 {
    print("they are equal")
}
```

> > ```
> > they are equal
> > ```

You will need another approach to find large factorials like the one shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830823/1630618).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.